# Getting public key information from a certificate file in iOS app

Tags: ios, encryption, certificate, key, public

I am working on an iOS app which communicates with a remote API. This API requires me to encrypt data with a public key stored in a `.cer` file (generated by OpenSSL on a Windows machine). I have included the `.cer` file in my project and I am using the following code to get me a certificate reference (at least that's what I think I did).

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSData *iosTrustedCertDerData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[bundle pathForResource:@"CertName" ofType:@"cer"]];
SecCertificateRef certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef) iosTrustedCertDerData);
```

After that I am pretty much stuck.I have been searching the web for a while, seeing various references to openssl.h. However, openssl only seems to be available for Mac, not iOS.

I can't stop wondering why I can't find any examples for working with certificates in your iOS app. Every time I search for certificates in iOS app, I get results explaining provisioning profiles etc. That's not what I am looking for.

I have found RNCryptor, but as far as I can see it's a Library for encrypting/decrypting, but no support for reading keys from certificates.

I am looking for a library (or code samples) on how to work with public keys stored in certificates, included in the application.
Something tells me I am on the wrong track.

When I am able to acquire the key from the certificate file, the encryption won't be a problem...hopefully.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I have been working on the iOS Security Framework for many weeks. There are no enough code samples for actually implementing lots of functions in the Security Framework.

After you get a reference to the Certificate, `SecCertificateCopyPublicKey` is not available in iOS SDK 8.2 though you can call using forward declaration. But it didn't work for me.

Finally, here is the solution for loading the certificate, getting the reference to the certificate data, create a X509 policy object and using SecTrust*() functions get the public key reference. Once you get the public key you can do the Encryption. **Note - This code is tested on XCode Version 6.2 (6C131e) and iOS SDK 8.2**

```
//1. Load certificate from main bundle
NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                     pathForResource:@"myTest" ofType:@"cer"];

//2. Get the contents of the certificate and load to NSData
NSData *certData = [[NSData alloc]
                    initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];

//3. Get CFDataRef of the certificate data
CFDataRef myCertData = (__bridge CFDataRef)certData;

SecCertificateRef myCert;
SecKeyRef aPublicKeyRef = NULL;
SecTrustRef aTrustRef = NULL;

//4. Create certificate with the data
myCert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, myCertData);

//5. Returns a policy object for the default X.509 policy
SecPolicyRef aPolicyRef = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();

if (aPolicyRef) {
    if (SecTrustCreateWithCertificates((CFTypeRef)myCert, aPolicyRef, &aTrustRef) == noErr) {
        SecTrustResultType result;
        if (SecTrustEvaluate(aTrustRef, &result) == noErr) {
            //6. Returns the public key for a leaf certificate after it has been evaluated.
            aPublicKeyRef = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(aTrustRef);
        }
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@", aPublicKeyRef);
```